# How to \label a long table without adding a new row?

Tags: cross-referencing, longtable

I wish to label a long table using `\label{long_table_1}`

However, when I insert it at the bottom of the page it shows

[image]

Notice there is another row sort of added to the table!

I cannot adjust the `\label` above the final `\hline` either because that triggers an error.

Can someone please tell me how I can `\label` a long table without inserting another row as above?

Example Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%Preamble

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}       
\usepackage{amsmath}              
\usepackage{amsfonts}              
\usepackage{amsthm}                
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{hyperref}                
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\title{Table Problem}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
{\bfseries Things I love about Mexico}
\begin{longtable}{ | m{5.5cm} | m{5.5cm} |}
    \hline 
    Princess Yagoda & Prince Khan\footnote{Tacos!}\\
    \hline
    \hline 
    
    {
    Uno
    } & Dos \\  
    \hline
    
    {
        Tres
    } & Quarto\\
    \hline 
    \label{The_Most_Important_Table_Ever}  %<---- Problem 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem of the lines happens because your table is not "finished" well, it is basically why it doesn't have "/ caption {*}" next to "/ label {*}"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For referencing of table you should in the first place to have table caption. A label should follows caption. `longtable` is designed so, that the caption has place in the table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%Preamble

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage{upgreek}
%\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{changepage}
%\usepackage{stackengine}
%\stackMath
%\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{supertabular}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor={red},citecolor={red},
            ]{hyperref}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}

\title{Table Problem}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\tableofcontents
%\newpage
\begin{longtable}{ | m{5.5cm} | m{5.5cm} |}
\caption{Things I love about Mexico}
    \label{The_Most_Important_Table_Ever}\\  %<---- Problem
    \hline
Princess Yagoda & Prince Khan\footnote{Tacos!}\\
    \hline
    \hline
Uno             & Dos \\
    \hline
Tres            & Quarto\\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
see table \ref{The_Most_Important_Table_Ever}
\end{document}
```

Above MWE gives:

[image]

Off-topic: in your preamble you have many packages load twice, `hyperref` had to be last in the preamble (with some exception not presented in your case), `supertabular` and `longtable` better not use in the same document. For better table looking I increase `\arraystretch` to 1.3. Also I comment all packages not relevant to your problem.

Comment: beware "well known" things: they are not always true:-)

Comment: actually this should be, however you are right, it is not :-). I will rephrase sentence.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for your clarification and helpful tips! Regards from Princess Yagoda and Prince Khan

Answer (score 4):

It isn't really specifically the `\label` that generates the spurious cell. *Anything* after the `\\` other than `\hline` or similar commands will start a new cell, `{}` or `\relax` for example.

You can place `\label` more or less anywhere in the table other than where you put it. It's pretty odd not to have a `\caption` as otherwise there is no visible number that relates to the generated `\ref` however it does work, as shown below. Normally I'd put `\label` inside the argument of `\caption` as in normal tables but:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%Preamble

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}       
\usepackage{amsmath}              
\usepackage{amsfonts}              
\usepackage{amsthm}                
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{hyperref}                
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\title{Table Problem}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
{\bfseries Things I love about Mexico}
\begin{longtable}{ | m{5.5cm} | m{5.5cm} |}
    \hline 
    Princess Yagoda & Prince Khan\footnote{Tacos!}\\
    \hline
    \hline 

    {
    Uno
    } & Dos\label{The_Most_Important_Table_Ever}  \\  
    \hline

    {
        Tres
    } & Quarto\\
    \hline 
\end{longtable}


see \ref{The_Most_Important_Table_Ever}
\end{document}
```